# Defining a Total Order

Tags: language-agnostic

How would you define a total order? For example, if you needed to define a total ordering or a shape, etc. How would you go about doing so?

Edit: Specifically, how would you define a total order based on an object with the coordinates (x,y,z). I don't understand how you could structure an ordering whereby each object is unique and sortable.

Comment: Sorry, I was very vague. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "natural" ordering on 2D or 3D objects. However, if you want to induce an ordering, you can compare them by their coordinates, for example this way:

```
// returns -1 if o1<o2, 1 if o1>o2, 0 if o1==o2
int Compare(MyObject o1 ,MyObject o2)
{
    if(o1.x>o2.x) return 1;
    if(o1.x<o2.x) return -1;
    if(o1.y>o2.y) return 1;
    if(o1.y<o2.y) return -1;
    if(o1.z>o2.z) return 1;
    if(o1.z<o2.z) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

This assumes objects are uniquely identified by their coordinates, of course.

This ordering will let you sort and compare such objects. The question you have to answer yourself is if it helps you for any of the problems you want to solve with that. An ordering on a 1D-set is typically used to make lookups faster, especially when you want not only a specific element from your set, but all elements from a given range.

For 2D or 3D sets, a similar question is to find all element sets within a given rectangle or cube. For that purpose, the order above does not support you very well. There are  datastructures like a 2D [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)  or 3D [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) supporting this task much better.

Comment: I'm sorry about the delay. But thanks a lot for your answer